# Parametric equation: tangents

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm not sure what it's called in English, but a curve can have different types of tangents and if a parametrization of the curve is given by $r(t)$, then if $r'(a) = 0$ and $r''(a) \neq 0$, then at that point we have a "cusp".

But is this a necessary condition? Or could there be points that fail above test despite being cusp points with the half-tangents going in the same direction?

Comment: From where I have encountered this term, I know that at a cusp, the velocity is zero, so I think $r'(a)=0$ is a necessary condition.